# Tools for Editing Azure Storage not working for Azure Stack

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-stack

I try to copy data from the public cloud to my Azure Stack Storage using the [tools proposed in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-stack/user/azure-stack-storage-transfer). Unfortunately, several of them are not working.
I managed to find a way using AzCopy. Unfortunately there is no such currently working alternative for deleting data. Therefore there is no way to clean the stack afterwards.

[image]

Might it be the same compatibility problem as for [my last problem appearing for the .NET storage api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49430739/azure-stack-table-storage-value-for-http-headers-not-in-correct-format/49480477?noredirect=1#comment85969872_49480477)? The error message seems to be the same: "Http Header not in correct format".

Comment: Are you using the correct version of the PowerShell cmdlets? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-stack/user/azure-stack-powershell-install. Azure Stack seems to require the cmdlet to access it using a specific version of the storage api that the normal (public cloud) Azure cmdlets, are not using.

Comment: This smells like you are not using right version of cmdlets / SDK. Install Fiddler and please attach the fiddler traces 400 bad request is not enough. One needs to see network traces for the REST API request.

Answer (score 0):

> Therefore there is no way to clean the stack afterwards.

Since it sounds like a one time taks: If the powershell cmdlets dont work, just use the AZ CLI instead.

az storage container delete -n [CONTAINER]  --connection-String [STRING]

Comment: Do you have experiences whether this works with AzureStack?

Comment: Yep. Worked a lot with both: azure Cli and storage Explorer. The azure cli command also works Fine.